# How to drag elements on Mobile Browser?

Tags: javascript, mobile, hammer.js

I'm trying to create a image cropper that should work on mobile; A big image is contained inside a container element that crops it, the user can drag the image inside this container and pinch to zoom.

The drag functionality works on desktop browser but when I'm testing in on mobile browser (android chrome, android internet browser, iphone safari), it doesn't work properly: it's not smooth or doesn't drag at all. It moves just a tiny, very tiny bits when trying to swipe or touch move.

Did some tests with touch, touchstart, touchmove without much luck:

I've got a demo in the following link ( http://jsbin.com/cokil/1/ ). Not sure if I can get some tips or advice on how to do this ?

- it was reported that the raw github link didn't load hammerjs (is loading here), so I've got this other loading it from a CDN http://jsbin.com/cokil/3/
- please remember that the issue is with mobile browsers

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Try jquery ui draggable

Comment: thanks for looking! I've opened it on my mobile browser and it doesn't work.

Comment: You just try to add mordernizer js also jquery & jquery ui then try it once
Add jquery then juery ui then mordernizer js

Comment: Then use draggble event

Comment: I'll try that, at the moment I found http://touchpunch.furf.com/ which may be a possible solution. Would be interesting if I could keep it simple without relying in to many external libraries, if that is possible ? I know I'm already using hammer.js, etc.

Comment: your js bin is not loading Hammer.js Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/master/hammer.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. 1:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Hammer is not defined

Comment: Also jquery + jquery ui + jquery ui touch punch is possibly the most bloated path to success imaginable. The code in the OP's bin is extremely simple, lets keep it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jsbin is not including Hammer js correctly. Replace:

`https://raw.github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/master/hammer.min.js`

with

`//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/1.0.6/hammer.min.js`

and your script works fine.

---

there is no need for jQuery in the script as it stands. You can use the native `DOMContentLoaded` and remove `$(document).ready` if you like.

---

You also need to add `'px'` to the end of your top and left declarations

```
imgEl.style.top = (y + parseFloat(event.gesture.deltaY))+'px';
imgEl.style.left = (x + parseFloat(event.gesture.deltaX))+'px';
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kimes/3)**

Comment: Hi @Fresheyeball! Thanks for looking, the raw github link didn't load for you ? That's a typo then, but the issue is that with hammerJs this doesn't work on mobile browsers. When you are trying to touch the element and drag it, it moves just a tiny tiny bit.

Comment: Its not a typo, github raw refuses to execute. Hammerjs absolutely does work on mobile browsers, thats about all its for. The problem is in your implementation. I have added a demo so you can see it working.

Comment: thanks for commenting on the solution below. You're right there's no need to interop, and the native scroll did stop this from working, as I don't noticed and came up with the interop. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of service ;)

Comment: it doesn't move the element from the last position it was after I drag again

Comment: @vsync demonstration?

Comment: here's a gif - http://giphy.com/gifs/yoJC2rMRiuRWHZOrny/fullscreen  tested on Firefox 32 / windows

Answer (score 0):

After researching quiet a lot, listening to what other people had to say about this and trying to keep things simple, I've come up with the following solution and hope is useful for someone else in the future:

```
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             var e = new Event('dragstart'); 
             element.dispatchEvent(e);
        }, false);

        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var e = new Event('drag'); 
            element.dispatchEvent(e);
        }, false);
```

This works by triggering the original code, that works on desktop:

```
        Hammer(element).on("dragstart", function(event) {

            imgEl = document.querySelectorAll("img")[0];

            y = parseFloat(imgEl.style.top) || 0;
            x = parseFloat(imgEl.style.top) || 0;
        });

        Hammer(element).on("drag", function(event) {

            imgEl.style.top = y + parseFloat(event.gesture.deltaY);
            imgEl.style.left = x + parseFloat(event.gesture.deltaX);

        });
```

Comment: There is no need to interop `touchmove` for hammerjs. Hammerjs already IS an interop for `touchmove` which is extremely well tested and mature for mobile browsers.